# launch error for kinect openni

Tags: ros, kinect, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I installed openni_kinect package and tried the launch command i'm not getting output. when i opened rviz i got the topics i selected them and changed to grey background according to the steps in openni_launch in ros, status for point cloud2 is warning and it says no messages received and [0] points from [0] messages.
when i opened launch command i got the following 2 errors:

```
root@kanna-Vostro-3550:~# roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
... logging to /home/kanna/.ros/log/2c9942c2-8928-11e1-9a4b-0567e511ceb2/roslaunch-kanna-Vostro-3550-23666.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://kanna-Vostro-3550:44496/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /rosversion
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range

NODES
  /camera/depth/
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
  /camera/
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/ir/
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [23680]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2c9942c2-8928-11e1-9a4b-0567e511ceb2
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23693]
started core service [/rosout]
process[camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [23705]
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [23706]
process[camera/rgb/debayer-4]: started with pid [23707]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-5]: started with pid [23714]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-6]: started with pid [23717]
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-7]: started with pid [23727]
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-8]: started with pid [23731]
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-9]: started with pid [23745]
process[camera/depth/metric-10]: started with pid [23747]
process[camera/depth/points-11]: started with pid [23764]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-12]: started with pid [23779]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [23793]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-14]: started with pid [23794]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-15]: started with pid [23798]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-16]: started with pid [23807]
process[camera/disparity_depth-17]: started with pid [23809]
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-18]: started with pid [23815]
process[camera_base_link-19]: started with pid [23816]
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [23825]
process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [23836]
process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [23842]
[ERROR] [1334734153.636038976]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1334734153.648738365]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1334734156.159765956]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1334734156.159985567]: 1. device on bus 003:11 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00362D00362137A'
[ INFO] [1334734156.162302192]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1334734156.225601716]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 3:11 with serial number 'A00362D00362137A'
[ INFO] [1334734156.282285682]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1334734156.282484197]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1334734156.292582267]: Camera calibration file /home/kanna/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00362D00362137A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1334734156.295726794]: Camera calibration file /home/kanna/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00362D00362137A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1334734156.298444373]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1334734156.298583148]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32080/launch-error-for-kinect-openni/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also get these errors, but still things work out.
You shouldn't run things as "root", but this is likely not the solution. Check wether data is sent on the topic:

```
rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/points
```

If so, the reason is most probably your rviz settings (correct frame_id chosen? try "/camera_link")

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-17**:
when i gave rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/points i got nothing. what is the problem.i didn't run in root this time. i changed to camera_link still nothing.wht to do

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-04-18**:
Try using (rosrun) dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui. You can set the openni_driver explicitly to "registered". Or you could try openni_camera, the previous kinect driver.

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-18**:
i tried registration steps given in openni_launch webpage even then no image,can u tell how to set openni_driver explicitly to registered i don't see any info on tht. i'm using electric so openni_camera is within the openni_kinect nd dunno how to get image using openni_cam pkg no webpage info too.

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-18**:
for the registration i'm not able to set the color transformer to RGB8, it doesn't show any option.

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-18**:
or is it because of the camera calibration warnings as u can see from my question above?

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-19**:
i got the output...i kept trying...i got it....thanx :)